# "It is learnt that..."

Tags: sentence-meaning

In Today's newspaper, I have read a sentence given below.

Can anyone please tell me, what is meaning of **It is learnt that** clause in the sentence or what that has been used/added in the sentence as i believe without clause it makes sense.

**It is learnt that** Mr. Prakash flagged the issue of autonomy of the corporation as the Ministry appointed Ms. Jain without consulting the Prasar Bharati Board.

Thanks,

Charmi

Comment: It's a preparatory it. It's used to shift (or delay) the main clause to the end of the sentence. This page should be useful: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv182.shtml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, the clause:

> It is learnt

Follows the pattern **it + be + adjective + that-clause** and uses the **it** as Damkerng points out in his comment as a preparatory subject with the real subject a that-clause.

Or simpler, this **it** can be regarded as a dummy subject of an impersonal verb like in:

> It rains.

or

> It is windy

Comment: @Charmi Sapariya, I feel flattered that you selected my answer but you should have waited for a day or so. By doing so you may discourage other answerers. [Don’t accept an answer too quickly](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer)

Comment: Technically, "it" here isn't a dummy subject like "it rains". It refers to the thing that was learnt - namely the knowledge of Mr. Prakesh's actions. The subject isn't featured at all - that is, the sentence states what was learnt but not who learnt it. This is typical of *passive voice*, which is commonly used for legal proceedings, academic papers, and similar formal writings. *The knowledge of Mr. Prakesh's actions was learned by an unspecified person or persons*. Whoever did the learning would be clear from context - usually, the writer, or whoever's behalf the writing is on (eg. a court).

Answer (score 2):

"It is learnt that" is equivalent to "It has been learnt that" in this context. This is a passive construction that indicates that what follows is new information has been gained without naming the source. This is common in journalism where sources often wish to remain private. Equivalent constructions are "It has come to light that" and "It has come to our attention that...".

As Lucian points out, this usage of *it* is often thought of as a dummy subject, although in my opinion it can also be said to be referring to the information that comes later in the sentence.